# C++ member array initalisation without default constructors

Tags: c++, clang, array-initialization

I have a class `Thing` sporting no default constructor.

Now we define another class, which now has to initalise the array elements at once, as without a default constructor, no late assignment can be made. So we have:

```
class TwoThings
{
    public:

    Thing things[2];

    TwoThings() : things({Thing("thing 1"),Thing("thing 2")})
    {
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way?

GCC compiles it fine, while Clang does not, stating an "initializer list" should be used. I tried several alternative ways like double braces `{{ ... }}` and such, but can't manage to get a compiling equivalent for Clang.

How to initialise arrays without default constructor in Clang?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, parenthesised member array initialization is a GCC extension. To make it standard, you can just use a single set of braces (requires C++11):

```
TwoThings() : things{Thing("thing 1"),Thing("thing 2")}
{
}
```

If you can't use C++11, you might want to use a different storage method, like `std::pair<Thing,Thing>` or `std::vector<Thing>`.

Comment: So there is no way without these extension or C++11 (breaks many of my older libraries) to initialize an array?

Comment: You could use a different storage method, like `std::pair<Thing,Thing>` or `std::vector<Thing>`.

Comment: I guess `std::vector` would need elements having the default constructor too?

Comment: No, you can use `reserve` and `push_back` instead of using `resize` to stop it from default constructing anything.